# Defining layout for activity in android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building and android app and have created the login screen. The next screen will show the logged in user a set of options from which he has to choose one.

The second activity is started from the `onPostExecute` method of an `AsyncTask` using the `startActivity(intent)` code.

```
Intent intent = null;
intent = new Intent(context, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

I am trying to build the UI for this screen using the .xml file `activity_display_message.xml`. The entry for this has been made to the manifest file.
Any of the layout attributes that I am specifying in this .xml file are not getting applied. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. For example using the code below I am unable to get the background color that I have set. This works fine with the .xml that I have for my main activity.

The onCreate function for my DisplayMessageActivity class is

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(CommonStaticValues.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    setContentView(textView);
}
```

The complete `activity_display_message.xml` file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="@color/background_color">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please show onCreate for the DisplayMessageActivity and the complete layout XML.

Comment: how background_color is defined?

Comment: I have a colors.xml file under res/values. This contains an entry for background_color much like the entries in strings.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems here that are probably causing your problem.  You first use `setContentView` like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
```

That applied your XML file to the Activity, which is want you want.  Later, you call it again with a `TextView` you created locally.  If you wanted an `Activity` that consisted of one `TextView` on the screen, that's one way to do it, but you don't need it here because you have an XML definition of the Activity already.

Secondly, your XML file's `TextView` has no android:id.  That's used to reference the `TextView` from the code.  So, modify your XML's `TextView` to add that like this:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:text="@string/hello_world"
tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" />
```

Then, back in your `onCreate`, instead of constructing a new `TextView` with `TextView textView = new TextView(this);`, access the `TextView` from the XML you applied like this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
```

Notice that the argument for `findViewById` is the id you create in the XML.